# Show a picture on my form, a certain time after the Load event.

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a picture appear on my form, a certain number of seconds after it loads, and then have that picture move in a controlled manner within the form boundaries. I'd appreciate a code example that will get me started with timed events.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int horiz, vert, step;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //image is moved at each interval of the timer

            goblin.Left = goblin.Left + (horiz * step);
            goblin.Top = goblin.Top + (vert * step);


            // if goblin has hit the RHS edge, if so change direction left
            if ((goblin.Left + goblin.Width) >= (Form1.ActiveForm.Width - step))
                horiz = -1;

            // if goblin has hit the LHS edge, if so change direction right
            if (goblin.Left <= step)
                horiz = 1;

            // if goblin has hit the bottom edge, if so change direction upwards
            if ((goblin.Top + goblin.Height) >= (Form1.ActiveForm.Height - step))
                vert = -1;

            // if goblin has hit the top edge, if so change direction downwards
            if (goblin.Top < step)
                vert = 1;
        }

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Soon as the forms loads activate the goblin to start moving 
            //set the intial direction
            horiz = 1;  //start going right
            vert = 1;   //start going down
            step = 5;   //moves goblin 5 pixels
            timer1.Enabled = true;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't it working?

Comment: this does work, my picture bounces around the screen. But what i am wanting is the picture to appear after 5 seconds when the form loads. Meaning the picture will be invisible, then after 5 seconds, the picture will be visible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is of the 'Plz snd me teh codez' type.

Comment: Be nice guys try to remember when you were a newer programmer and what helped you learn. When I was 12 I had to have someone explain to me how a ball would bounce in pong because I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution based on what you've shown us so far is to use the same timer you are using already and essentially skip a few ticks. Let's assume that your current timer is happening at `100ms` which is 10 timers per second (10hz)

If you want to delay this activity by 5 seconds, you need to skip `5 * 10` (50) of the first ticks. Create a new integer member variable to store how many ticks you've processed:

```
private int ticks = 0;
```

Each time the timer expires/ticks do this first:

```
ticks++;

if (ticks < 50) {
     // Don't do anything just skip
     return;
}
```

Comment: can you please put this coding into my code please, as i dont know where to put it, i would really appreciate it if you could thankyou. and yes the timers intervel is 100ms

Comment: :( haha, but i tried it but it doesnt work as nothing happens

Comment: I'd put `ticks++` inside the conditional block. Otherwise you'd end up getting an overflow exception and crash.

Comment: Yes it will overflow after about 2 years

Answer (score 1):

You can provide second 'temporary' timer (timer2)

```
private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Soon as the forms loads activate the goblin to start moving 
    //set the intial direction
    horiz = 1;  //start going right
    vert = 1;   //start going down
    step = 5;   //moves goblin 5 pixels
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick_1;

    // temporary timer
    Timer timer2 = new Timer();
    timer2.Interval = 5000;
    timer2.Tick += delegate
    {
        // activate goblin timer
        timer1.Enabled = true;

        // deactivate 5s temp timer
        timer2.Enabled = false;
        timer2.Dispose();
    };
    timer2.Enabled = true;
}
```